# Android Volley GET Request with username and password fails

Tags: android, get, request, android-volley

The following Android Volley GET Request is failing with the following error message:

```
E/Volley: [1038] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for
```

This is the Request:

```
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    final String url = "https://xxxxxxxx/storage/v1/items";

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                StringBuilder formattedResult = new StringBuilder();
                JSONArray responseJSONArray = response.getJSONArray("items");
                for (int i = 0; i < responseJSONArray.length(); i++) {
                    formattedResult.append("\n" + responseJSONArray.getJSONObject(i).get("no") + "=> \t" + responseJSONArray.getJSONObject(i).get("ean")
                            + "=> \t" + responseJSONArray.getJSONObject(i).get("name")
                            + "=> \t" + responseJSONArray.getJSONObject(i).get("type")
                            + "=> \t" + responseJSONArray.getJSONObject(i).get("destruction")
                            + "=> \t" + responseJSONArray.getJSONObject(i).get("archived")
                    );
                }
                txtShowTextResult.setText("List of Items \n" + " Number" + "\t EAN \n" +
                        "\t Name \n" +  "\t Type \n" + formattedResult);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            txtShowTextResult.setText("An Error occured while making the request");
        }
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            String credentials = "username:password";
            String auth = "Basic "
                    + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.put("Authorization", auth);
            return headers;
        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

I am not sure why the Request is failing, as I am new to Android Volley.

Possible cause: the method getHeaders() is not called, but I don´t know where to put the Method call in the Request and therefore, I would appreciate any help, hints or feedback. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Prolly is not called... As you put it in wrong class... It should be prolly method of Request not ErrorListener

Comment: Hi @Selvin could you detail this a bit? Not sure what you mean

Comment: 401 points to unauthorized access so your suspicion about header not set correctly could be correct. In order to set header override getHeader method as you did for onResponse and onError

Comment: @georkost: Ok, thank you for the input - could you detail that a bit? How and where would I override getHeader that method? Because that´s exactly the part that´s unclear to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the missing part at your code you can try out the following. Notice the `override` part of `getHeaders`, let me know how it goes.

```java
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        //handle response
                    }
                }
                , new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //handle error
            }
        }){
            @NotNull
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                //Handle headers inside here
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                String credentials = "username:password";
                String auth = "Basic "
                        + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                headers.put("Authorization", auth);
                return headers;
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```